# Test valid/invalid string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm testing if a string is valid/invalid by checking if certain characters exists. Strings that contain ; # / % = | + \ " < > are deemed invalid. I've the following implementation in Java currently, but I'd prefer a more elegant regex solution.

```
public boolean isStringValid(String name) {
    if (   name.contains(";")
        || name.contains("#")
        || name.contains("/")
        || name.contains("%")
        || name.contains("=")
        || name.contains("|")
        || name.contains("+")
        || name.contains("\\")
        || name.contains("\"")
        || name.contains("<")
        || name.contains(">")) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I've done is changed it to the following,

```
public boolean isNameValid(String name) {
    return !Pattern.matches(".*(;|#|/|%|=|\\||\\+|\\\\|\"|<|>)+.*", name);
}
```

but I can't seem to get the regex string right. The original regex string before adding in all the Java escape characters is as follows,

```
.*(;|#|/|%|=|\||\+|\\|"|<|>)+.*
```

Using character classes like [A-z] doesn't seem to be an option because a name like "d@vik" is supposed to be considered valid in my case.

Comment: When you want to check something, it is better to check for validity than for some cases of invalidity.

Comment: @popfalushi I would normally agree with you, but I'm just writing an automated test script based on the specifications I'm given. Who knows what the developers had in mind? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right. Just use `find()` method instead of `matches()`. And compile pattern only once. This is the most expensive operation. And you can simplify you pattern using `[` `]`: in this case you do not have to write `|` between subpatterns you are looking for:

```
private static Pattern validator = Pattern.compile("[;%#=\\+]"); // etc: write all characters you need.
```

Now re-write you `isNameValid()` as following:

```
public boolean isNameValid(String name) {
    return !validator.find();
}
```

BTW pay attention on backslash. If you want your pattern to include backslash it should be written 4 times: twice for regex escaping and twice for java escaping.

Comment: +1 for find. But the pattern isn't complete, I think it should be `Pattern.compile("[;#/%=\\|\\+\\\\\"<>]")`

Comment: @RolandBouman, you don't need to escape `+` and `|` inside a character class.

Comment: @RolandBouman and AlexR Thank you both. One thing though, the Validator class doesn't seem to have a find(), but rather it is a method of Matcher. So the return code would look this: return !validator.matcher(name).find(); Correct me if I'm wrong, or let me know if I'm right so I can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can negate character classes:

```
Pattern.matches("[^;#/%=|+\\\\\"<>]+", name);
```